# How to search for record in mongodb without mentioning the field name?

Tags: mongodb

I am searching for a query in mongodb that will satisfied my search condition.I have a record in the db collection:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("5b3d970398e9d099427896c3"),
 "role": "New Booking is there by abc",
 "date": "07/04/2018",
 "idaddress": "213.123.123.213",
 "booking": {
   "bedroom": 4,
   "bathroom": 6,
   "customer": "abc",
   "email": "abc@gmail.com",
   "provider": "provider1",
   "address": "brazil",
   "appt": "123456",
   "phone": "987654321"
 }
}
```

In this record `booking` object have 8 fields and for searching I am using the Query:

```
db.collection_name.find({ "booking.field_name" : {$regex : /data$/}})
```

To search a value that match from each field (customer, email, provider, address, appt, phone) I have to write the same line with field name, but if I have 100 fields under the booking object then I need to write the same line 100 times with each field name.
I am looking for a query that search from each field, for this I have tried the $text clause like:                                                                       bson.M{"_id": bson.M{'$type': "objectId" } }
But $text clause will only search the full word not regular expression(Stemmed Words) word Example:- `"This is a string"` in this line I want to search the  `"str"` word but it will not showing the matching record with it.

Will anyone suggest any example for it. It will take my lot of time.

For helping me solving this problem Thank you.

Comment: You need to manage your document structure so that you do not have 500 fields. Also your booking is not a array it is an object.

Comment: lol sorry for this mistake @prajvalM so what structure should I have to flow to make it easier??

Comment: Why would you have 500 fields

Comment: @prajvalm because the object will retrieve according the changes done by the user so I'm taking an example of that if user changes many field according to him/her

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation framework is the way. As @Prajval said, you have an object, so the solution is to convert it in array before querying. Here's the code :

```
db.test1.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                role:1,
                date:1,
                idadress:1,
                booking_values:{$objectToArray:"$booking"}
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

This will output

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3d970398e9d099427896c3"), 
    "role" : "New Booking is there by abc", 
    "date" : "07/04/2018", 
    "booking_values" : [
        {
            "k" : "bedroom", 
            "v" : NumberInt(4)
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "bathroom", 
            "v" : NumberInt(6)
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "customer", 
            "v" : "abc"
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "email", 
            "v" : "abc@gmail.com"
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "provider", 
            "v" : "provider1"
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "address", 
            "v" : "brazil"
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "appt", 
            "v" : "123456"
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "phone", 
            "v" : "987654321"
        }
    ]
}
```

From here you can easily add aggregation stages to get the exact result you need. (whole documents or just booking values that match criteria, criterias on booking field name (k), booking field value(v) or both, etc...)

If you need help to achieve this, just provide your expected result.

Comment: there is an error see i will run this command `db.system.aggregate[{$project: {role:1, date:1, idadress:1, booking_values:{$objectToArray:"$booking"}}},]);` which gives me the error of `E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']' @(shell):1:105`

Comment: Oh, that's nice.

Comment: @puneet55667788: that command is not quite what matthPen suggested. Pay more attention.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes sir sorrry for that can you tell me that I'm saying right or wriong `matthPen` says that by using that command  all the field will change into the `k` and `v` form then I will easy to search the record by using the single line command. right?

Comment: ohhh Thank you sir for it @SergioTulentsev and `matthPen`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you please tell me how will I right this Query in golang

Comment: There is a one question to in my mind that this query will use while the time of saving the record or while fetching??

Comment: @puneet55667788: "while the time of saving the record or while fetching?" - this is usage of a feature called "aggregation pipeline". Read up on it. Will clear some confusion.

Comment: this is a fetching command, but you can add as last stage ["$out"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to output your aggregation results in a new collection.